# Scipy clustering: which method to use in fcluster for simple grouping?

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-analysis

There are myriad of optins in the [scipy clustering module](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.hierarchy.html#module-scipy.cluster.hierarchy), and I'd like to be sure that I'm using them correctly. I have a symmetric distance matrix `DR` and I'd like to find all clusters such that any point in the cluster has a neighbor with a distance of no more than 1.2.

```
L = linkage(DR,method='single')
F = fcluster(L, 1.2)
```

In `linkage`, I'm pretty sure `single` is what I want (the Nearest Point Algorithm). However for `fcluster`, I *think* I want the default, ‘inconsistent’, method:

> ‘inconsistent’: If a cluster node and all its descendants have an inconsistent value less than or equal to t then all its leaf descendants belong to the same flat cluster. When no non-singleton cluster meets this criterion, every node is assigned to its own cluster. (Default)

But maybe it's the ‘distance’ method:

> ‘distance’: Forms flat clusters so that the original observations in each flat cluster have no greater a cophenetic distance than t.

... I'm not sure. Which one to use? What does cophenetic distance distance mean in this context?

Comment: You might want to look at DBSCAN. See the Wikipedia article on it. It looks like you are looking for an output of DBSCAN with minPts=1 and epsilon=1.2

Comment: @Anony-Mousse looking it over on wikipedia, it seems that DBSCAN is _exactly_ what I'm talking about. The question can now be phrased: Is DBSCAN implemented in `scipy`?

Comment: It's fairly simple to implement judging from the pseudocode on wikipedia, in particular since you already seem to have a distance matrix. Just do it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at DBSCAN. See the Wikipedia article on it. It looks like you are looking for an output of DBSCAN with minPts=1 and epsilon=1.2

It's fairly simple to implement judging from the pseudocode on wikipedia, in particular since you already seem to have a distance matrix. Just do it yourself.

Comment: One would want to have a look at how others did it. My implementation: https://bitbucket.org/jgehrcke/python_molecular_structure_comparison/src/tip/clusteringdbscan.py?at=default and scikit-learn's implementation: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/cluster/dbscan_.py

Comment: There is a somewhat official implementation of DBSCAN available in ELKI. It supports two dozens of similarity measures, has full indexing support for acceleration, and there are also enhanced algorithms such as OPTICS, PreDeCon etc. available. I'd start with this implementation.

Comment: Right you are, ELKI is a framework written by the original authors of DBSCAN (and other algorithms), but ELKI is not exactly Python :-)